# Moment Showing incorrect time ago in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a react app that adds posts and the posts are stored with timestamps in the database. I am using `moment` to get the time the posts were published. But if I submit a post now, it will always display Published 3 hours ago. The time is always 3 hours earlier. Kindly help.

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Code to Display Time

```
{moment.utc(post.posttime).fromNow()}
```

Kindly help. Thank you

Comment: Most likely that the times are being stored/retrieved in UTC and you need to convert them to your local timezone. This is just a guess though, as there's not enough details or debugging info in the question.

Comment: Note that moment.js went into legacy status over 2 years ago.  See their [project page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for details and alternatives.